# SWF file not printing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I use the fusioncharts api for drawing the chart. In chrome when i try to print chart(.swf file) using window.print(), chart does not show in print window while ohter HTML content shows.

Although, doing a right click on chart, only the chart shows and not the HTML content.

How to print the chart and HTML content together?

Comment: swf is not "other HTML content" - it's not even "HTML content" - it's Adobe Flash content - does Chrome have a print option to include background images or maybe some option to include "embedded" content in printing?

Comment: Yes, swf is Adobe flash content. Yes its has other embedded content for printing. Even the same code is working in IE.